# CSS Issue in IE7 and IE8 - text-indent on <input type="text"> field

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

Is it possible to make IE7 and IE8 respect the text-indent css property on an input field?

Here's my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
        <input type="text" style="text-indent:100px; display:block;" value="Test indent" />
</body>
</html>
```

When you first load the page in IE8, the text is NOT indented.  You can "activate" the text-indent property by focussing in on the text field and typing into it (ie. trigger the onchange event).

How do I make IE7 and IE8 respect the text-indent of an input text element on page load instead of on input.onchange event?

Comment: why do you need this? Perhaps there's another way.

Comment: normally i would use padding-left or margin-left...but because of something else i'm doing, i'm going to have to rely on text-indent

Comment: using something outside of it's intention is not advised. As @gelogenic said below, `text-indent` is meant for indenting the first line. An `inline` element (such as `input`) won't necessarily respect this if it's not the first item in a paragraph.

Comment: this input field is only meant to have one line.  If I wanted multiline, I woudl have used `textarea`

Comment: an `input` field is no different than a `span` in this case. `<p>This is a <input type="text" value="test"/></p>` is (likely) one line of text. `"test"` is not it's own line unless the `input` is `display: block;` A `textarea` element is a `block level` element (like a `p` tag).

Answer (score 13):

in normal case input tag text-indent does not work in ie6 and ie7
If we add lineheight:1px it will work all browser

Text-indent  will work all browser

```
<input type="text" style="text-indent:-100px; display:block; line-height:1px;" value="Test indent" />
```

Text-indent  not will work ie7 and ie6 browser

```
<input type="text" style="text-indent:-100px; display:block;" value="Test indent" />
```

demo

http://jsfiddle.net/KczMR/1/

Comment: It seems any line-height will work, so it's better to write line-height: 1em;

Comment: Thanks getting input text to be hidden is hard in IE

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you want 'text-indent' instead of either the 'margin-left' or the 'padding-left' property? The 'text-indent' property is meant to affect only the first line of text in an element. You might have better luck with margin or padding.

Comment: normally i would use padding-left or margin-left...but because of something else i'm doing, i'm going to have to rely on text-indent